# Dynamically Changing values using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i dynamically change values for my paragraphs depending on the product selected?

In my code this is what is happening. When i select `MacBook` and enter the qty, i am able the actual total price but after i select another product, it globally changes the `Total` for every product already selected.

```
    Item: MacBook 

    Amount : 8900

    Qty : 1

    Total : 1200


   Item : HP Probook

   Amount : 1200

   Quantity: 1

   Total:  1200
```

**JS**

```
 function OptionsSelected(product)
{

    $('.container').append(
        '<div class="product">'+
     '<input type="hidden"  value='+product.id+'    name="product[] />'+
     '<p class="name"> Item: ' + product.name + '</p>'+
        '<p class="price"   data-price="'+product.value+'">Price  :  ' + product.value + '</p>'+
        '<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" />'+
        '<p class="total">Total  $:<span></span></p>'+
         '</div>'

    ).appendTo('form')

    $('.container').on('keyup','.quantity',function()

       {
        var a = Number($(this).val());
        var b = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));    
        c = a * b;
        //debugger --breakpoint
        alert('Debugging prices for items selected  ' +b);

        $(".total span").text(c);

       });
```

**HTML**

```
  <input onclick="return OptionsSelected(this)" type="checkbox" id="{!! $product->id !!}" name="{!! $product->name !!}" value="{!! $product->price !!}" /> 

<div class="container" id="container">


</div>
```

**PS**:I tried to create a working snippet but i couldn't get that working and this is a new thread for a question already asked

Comment: Every call of `OptionsSelected` adds a new `keyup` event listener to `#container`

Comment: @Andreas  How is that affecting it please? If you could elaborate

Comment: What if in jQuery you write as   $("#yourID").keydown(function () {
                 OptionsSelected();
             });

Comment: @AliSajid i don't understand your statement

Comment: 1. I'm only showing you problems with your code. If it should have been an answer to the problem, I would have added it as an answer. 2. There's at least one missing quote in: `value='+product.id+' name="product[] />'` 3. There's no code related to .total in your question

Comment: I have added the quote and as well update `.total` in the question. But it didn't resolve my issue

Comment: But now the actual problem is included in the question!

Comment: Exactly but then i can't see why my code globally changes the total price for every selected item

Comment: $(".total span").text(c) changes the text for ALL classes matching that selector. Might be where the unexpected behavior is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
$(".total span").text(c);
```

changes the content of every element which has the class `total`

Use `this` (as already done to get the correct quantity) to only change the `.total` of the changed product

```
$('.container').on('keyup', '.quantity', function () {
    var quantityInput = $(this);
    var product = quantityInput.closest('div');

    var quantity = Number(quantityInput.val());
    var price = Number(product.find('.price').data('price'));

    product.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should target your appended product by an id and use this id as selector to attach the keyup event:

```
function OptionsSelected(product)
{

  $('.container').append(
      '<div class="product" id=product'+ product.id +'>'+
      '<input type="hidden"  value='+product.id+'    name="product[] />'+
      '<p class="name"> Item: ' + product.name + '</p>'+
      '<p class="price"   data-price="'+product.value+'">Price  :  ' + product.value + '</p>'+
      '<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" />'+
      '<p class="total">Total  $:<span></span></p>'+
      '</div>'

   );

   $(document).find('#product'+product.id+'>.quantity').keyup(function() {
      var a = Number($(this).val());
      var b = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));    
      c = a * b;

      $(this).next('.total').children('span').text(c);

   });

}
```

Try this fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pq02bzrL/)